# How do I sum rows in pandas by the first word of each row into an aggregate for that first word?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

for instance in column named 'fruit'

```
'fruit'      val1 val2
apple bottom  1    2 
apple shot    3    4
```

output:

```
apple 4 6
```

If the above is tin a dataframe how do I get the output?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little shorter version of proposed answer by @Nk03:

```
df.groupby(df.fruit.str.split(' ').str[0]).sum()
```

output:

```
       val1 val2
fruit       
apple   4   6
```

if your column name has a space in it like OP's comment, use:

```
df.groupby(df[' line item'].str.split(' ').str[0]).sum()
```

Comment: how about if instead of the column being 'fruit' it was called ' line item' ? with a space in between the column name?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose if you have got a df like this:

```
          fruit  val1  val2
0  apple bottom     1     2
1    apple shot     3     4
```

You can achieve the result via `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby(df.fruit.str.split(' ').str[0].values).agg({'val1':  sum, 'val2' : sum})
```

Output:

```
       val1  val2
apple     4     6
```

`NOTE`: You can specify the different method in the `dict` inside `agg`.
If you need just the `sum` then you can always use the smaller version.

```
df = df.groupby(df.fruit.str.split(' ').str[0]).sum()
```

Comment: how about if fruit is 'fruit line' instead? how do i enter col name with a space? its the first column